# How do I prove there exists a such measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $V$ be a closed subspace of $L^2([-1/2,1/2]^n)$.

Let $f:(S^1)^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function.

Define $\rho:[-1/2,1/2]^n\rightarrow (S^1)^n:x\mapsto (e^{2\pi i x_1},...,e^{2\pi i x_n})$.

I have proven that for each continuous function $f\in C((S^1)^n,\mathbb{C})$, $f\circ \rho \in V$.

With this information, how do I prove that $V=L^2([-1/2,1/2]^n)$?

Since $C([-1/2,1/2]^n,\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $L^2([-1/2,1/2]^n)$, it suffices to prove that $C([-1/2,1/2]^n,\mathbb{C})$ is contained in $V$.

However, I'm stuck here. Let $f:[-1/2,1/2]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Then, does there exist $g\in C((S^1)^n,\mathbb{C})$ such that $||g\circ \rho -f||_2 <\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon>0$? How do I prove this?

I have an idea but it is really hard to formalize the proof. I want a formal one..

Comment: Of course there is such a $g$, namely $f \circ \rho$.  That's not what you need.  You need to start with a $g$ and approximate it by $f \circ \rho$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Edited thank you!

Comment: My idea is this. Note that $f$ is bounded. Hence, consider a domain $[-1/2,1/2-\delta]^n$ such that the measure of $[-1/2,1/2]^n \setminus [-1/2,1/2-\delta]^n$ is smaller than $\epsilon/M$. Then, expand the restricted $f$ on this small rectangle to the original rectangle to construct such $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start by defining $g$ on $\rho([-1/2,1/2-\delta]^n)$, where $\delta > 0$ is sufficiently small, to make $g \circ \rho = f$ on $[-1/2, 1/2-\delta]^n$, and extend to all of $(S^1)^n$ using the Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: this was somewhat in my mind. I did not think to apply Tietze on $(S^1)^n$! But I tried to apply Tietze on $[-1/2,1/2-\delta]^n$ and this was where I was stuck. Thank you!